# Vue Test utils custom event trigger is not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-test-utils, custom-events, primevue

I am trying to write a test for my parent component, where I want to trigger the `doSomething` method and assert that operation.

**Parent Component:**

```
<div>
 <DropdownContainer v-model="selectedTitle" title="dropdown-title" 
                    :options="dropdownOption" @load-data="doSomething"
                    dropdown-data-test="dropdown-test"/>
</div>

doSomething() {
 console.log('I am getting called');
}
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
<Dropdown :model-value="modelValue" :options="options" :data-test="dropdownDataTest"
          @change="emitEvent">
</Dropdown>
</template>

export default {
name: "DropdownContainer",
emits: ['update:modelValue', 'load-data'],
methods: {
  emitEvent(event) {
    this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.value);
    this.emitChangeEvent && this.$emit('load-data')
  }
}
}
```

```
parent-component.spec.js
```

```
 it('should call dropdown load-data method',async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(Parent)
        const dropdown = wrapper.findComponent('[data-test="dropdown-test"]')

        await dropdown.trigger('load-data');
    });
```

Now, here when I run the test, the test passes as there is no assertion but I don't see the parent's component `doSomething` console log getting called.

But if I change the `emits` declaration in the child component from `emits: ['update:modelValue', 'load-data']` to `emits: ['update:modelValue']`

then my parent component test passes and prints the console log, which means the parent component actually called the `doSomething` method, I am not sure why.

Is there anything that I am doing wrong because as per the official docs we should list all the emitted events but my test is failing because of that. Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using Vue3, Vue/test-utils and Primevue component library. The feature is working fine, its just the test issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the [.trigger](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#trigger). As docs says it fires event on the DOM node. If you explicitly specifying the event in `emits` block it says that your **component** will fire it. Otherwise VTU just trigger the `load-data` event as DOM node event.

In your case you shoud use `$emit`

```
wrapper.findComponent('[data-test="dropdown-test"]').vm.$emit('load-data')

await wrapper.vm.$nextTick() // Wait until $emits have been handled
// then
expect(wrapper.emitted('first-event'))...
expect(wrapper.emitted('second-event'))...
```

Comment: But in this case I will be emiting this data in the test also, then the testing for the emitted part cannot be done, right?

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava why not? It can. Use https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#emitted

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava oh I'm sorry. I get it wrong. In your case you should check if `doSomething` is called. It depends on what this function does. If it changes html - you should check if html was changed

Comment: So the task of doSomething is to emit 2 different event. If i assert on just whether doSomething is called then changing any line inside my function, will not fail my test. This was the reason I want to assert whether the 2 event emitted from doSomething got emitted or not. If I need to emit them then the test purpose will not be fulfilled.

Comment: @AnkitaSrivastava You don't need to emit event that you want to test, of course. 1. you are emitting events from your `child` component `wrapper.findComponent('[data-test="dropdown-test"]').vm.$emit('load-data')` 2. You are checking 2 emitted events `wrapper.emitted` from  your parent component. I updated the answer